# Как на php получить тики текущей даты

Tags: php, .net

В `.NET` есть простой способ получить тики :

```
var ticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
Console.WriteLine(ticks);
// Output: 636737386875592894
```

Как получить такой же результат на `php` ? Нашел пока только функцию `microtime()` но она возвращает значения до милисекунды а не до `ticks`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817574/get-time-ticks-in-php На соседнем форме смотрели?

Comment: @AntonKomyshan ответ от @Samosa дает точность до наносекунд. т.е. полученное значение нужно  `* 100` и сложить с `621355968000000000`. Это все еще не тики.

Comment: Да, не тики всё же. Ну если прям так точно нужно - то на сколько я понял в php нету инструмента который даёт это из коробки, нужно писать или C++ врапер, который будет у себя считать тики, или попробовать использовать вызов .NET `DateTime` в php: http://php.net/manual/en/class.dotnet.php

Comment: @AntonKomyshan знал что js не умеет доставать тики, не думал что и php тоже.

Comment: Видать это мало кому нужно. Интересно конечно: зачем это Вам?

Comment: @AntonKomyshan для формирования на их базе UUID v.1 Как это сделать тоже пока не знаю.

Comment: @Сергей а как у других сделано смотрели? Например тут https://packagist.org/packages/ramsey/uuid

Comment: @ЕгорБанин там есть описание как получить uuid на основании текущего таймспана, а мне нужно, задавать явно.

Comment: @AntonKomyshan можно, используя `system`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что можно получать текущее время с точностью до наносекунды прямо из системы, а т.к. в одном тике 100 наносекунд то следующий код вполне точно выведет тики :

```
$nanotime = exec('date +%s%N');
$ticks = ((int)$nanotime/100) + 621355968000000000;
echo "<br>".(int)$ticks."<br>";
//636738208070352128
```